# Copy Approver Comments to Requested Item

Tags: servicenow

Currently I have a business rule setup on the Approval table to run when the comments field changes. I need to copy the comment from the approver comments to the requested item. I am new to ServiceNow so I am still learning the platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
(function executeRule(current, previous) {

  var gr = new GlideRecord('sc_req_item');
  gr.get(current.sysapproval);
  gr.comments = current.comments.toString();
  gr.update();

})(current, previous);
```